# How to implement the same checks inside each class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose there is an `Account` class. This class has the `__authorized` property. There is a `get` method which gets account data and sets `__authorized` to `True`. And there are many other methods for working with account (e.g. `method_1`, `method_2`, `method_3`, etc.).

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__authorized = False
    
    def get(self):
        # do some staff
        self.__authorized = True

    def method_1(self):
        pass

    def method_2(self):
        pass

    def method_3(self):
        pass
```

In each method I need to put a check for `__authorized` at the very beginning. If `__authorized == False`, then raise an exception.

I see 2 options: either manually write this condition in each method or create a decorator and wrap all class methods in it.

First option:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__authorized = False
    
    def get(self):
        # do some staff
        self.__authorized = True

    def method_1(self):
        if not self.__authorized:
            raise Exception("The account is not authorized with the get method!")

    def method_2(self):
        if not self.__authorized:
            raise Exception("The account is not authorized with the get method!")

    def method_3(self):
        if not self.__authorized:
            raise Exception("The account is not authorized with the get method!")
```

Second option:

```
def check_account_authorized(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not args[0].is_authorized():
            raise Exception("The account is not authorized with the get method!")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__authorized = False

    def get(self):
        # do some staff
        self.__authorized = True

    @check_account_authorized
    def method_1(self):
        pass

    @check_account_authorized
    def method_2(self):
        pass

    @check_account_authorized
    def method_3(self):
        pass

    def is_authorized(self):
        return self.__authorized
```

However, these methods seem to me wrong and cumbersome.

Is there a more elegant / correct way to implement `__authorized` checking in every class method?

Comment: Why aren't you doing your init in, well, `__init__`? That's what it's for.

Comment: @wim because in order to work with an account, you must first get some data about the account by making several requests. I do this in the get method.

Comment: @wim, if it makes more sense, self.__initiated can be replaced with self.__authorized

Comment: sidenote: why the underscores? Whether the account is ready for "doing things with" is a normal property, not a magic "dunder" property.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, so that this property cannot be edited from the outside.

Comment: Just because a property uses double _ characters, doesn't mean it cannot be edited, it just is a c0ommon usage signal that it shouldn't be edited

Comment: @itprorh66, yes, I understand that. That's what I meant. However, double underscore complicates this process a bit, because to change this property you will have to write not just `instance.__authorized`, but `instance._Account__authrized` + it will not appear in tooltips in the IDE.

Comment: @JeJe, what do you mean?

Comment: IMO the decorator approach is better because you don't have to repeat the `if... raise` code over and over. Why do you think this is "wrong and cumbersome" or inelegant? You're going to have to mark methods that perform the check somehow, and a decorator isn't overly verbose and repetetive

Comment: I don't really understand your *question*. What is *wrong with your second approach*? What is cumbersome about it?

Comment: Is it possible for an account to become *deauthorized*? I might suggest two classes: one represents an account that needs to be authorized and has a method that produces an instance of the other, which has all the actual methods that require authorization. No checks are needed, because the existence of the second instance implies authorization has succeeded.

Comment: (Even deauthorization might be handled by dynamically changing the type back to the first class, but that's definitely a bit unorthodox.)

Comment: I also think the decorator is not bad. Several popular frameworks do it that way. You have to distinguish between auth methods and the others somehow, and the alternative is to have some list of them somewhere else, which is less obvious from a readability standpoint because it's so decoupled from the def itself.